# How to determine the current language of a wordpress page when using polylang?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I search for a variable that outputs the currently used language of the polylang plugin. Something like:

```
if($curlang == "en") {
  ...
}
```

Comment: fixed grammar; paragraphs

Answer (score 102):

We can use the [`get_locale`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/) function:

```
if (get_locale() == 'en_GB') {
    // drink tea
}
```

Answer (score 26):

To show current language, you can use:

```
 <?php echo $lang=get_bloginfo("language"); ?>
```

Plain and simple

Comment: Would that not gives the relative current user locale? If my user admin setting is english and site in german, any ajax related loaded content (like an calendar) on front will be english. To get the absolute locale for all scenarios, I use get_option('WPLANG')

Comment: Yes, strange if global wp_locale in ajax calls if lang differ from admin user and front end. get_option('WPLANG') and get_bloginfo('language') returns different values.

Answer (score 25):

> ### [pll_current_language](https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/)
>
> Returns the current language
>
> #### Usage:
>
> ```
> pll_current_language( $value );
> ```
>
> - $value => (optional) either *name* or *locale* or *slug*, defaults to *slug*
>
> returns either the full
> name, or the WordPress locale (just as the WordPress core function
> ‘get_locale’ or the slug ( 2-letters code) of the current language.

Comment: how can you access this function from a different plugin? I get the error "Call to undefined function pll_current_language()"

Comment: @coding-dude.com you cannot. This is a function of polylang.

Answer (score 20):

***Simple:***

```
if(pll_current_language() == 'en'){
   //do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This plugin is documented rather good in https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation.

### Switching post language

The developers documentation states the following logic as a means to generate URL's for different translations of the same post

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<ul class='translations'><?php pll_the_languages(array('post_id' =>; $post->ID)); ?></ul>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If you want more influence on what is rendered, inspet `pll_the_languages` function and copy it's behaviour to your own output implementation

### Switching site language

As you want buttons to switch language, this page: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/frequently-asked-questions/the-language-switcher/ will give you the required info.

An implementation example:

```
<ul><?php pll_the_languages();?></ul>
```

Then style with CSS to create buttons, flags or whatever you want.
It is also possible to use a widget for this, provided by te plugin

### Getting current language

All plugins functions are explained here: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/

In this case use:

```
pll_current_language();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I think it is not exactly what I searched for. I have a Button on the Header of every page. I want to have two links, one for the german and another for the english version of the site.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please refer to the documentation provided by the developer as well. If this answer combined with the documentation is not enough, please refine your question further

Comment: I already translated the button caption but it is about the href link behind it.

Comment: In fact I only need a variable in php that tells me what language is actually shown and then I can output one of the two links with a if statement.

Comment: Sorry but i think i have to withdraw my answer. I'm now completely confused about what the question is. The links generated by the above code will switch the language of the site. My previous answer switches the language of the post.

Comment: Updated the answer. Did i get lucky and help you with this version? :)

Answer (score 10):

I use something like this:

```
<?php 

$lang = get_bloginfo("language"); 

if ($lang == 'fr-FR') : ?>

   <p>Bienvenue!</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
                    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                    $eep=explode('/',$currentpage);
                    $ln=$eep[1];
                    if (in_array("en", $eep))
                    {
                        $lan='en';
                    }
                    if (in_array("es", $eep))
                    {
                        $lan='es';
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Actually this is the only solution that worked for me when trying to get the current language from a custom plugin I'm writing. All other solutions returned the default wordpress language. I guess plugins are loaded before wordpress determines the current language.