# How do I check which language file (.mo) is being used for my Wordpress (Woocommerce) child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, translation

I understand this has been asked many times before but I haven't been able to find a solution for my situation yet. I've been guessing the issue for a while now since I don't know how to check what .mo file is being loaded.

I have wordpress set to my language in the settings, a translated .mo file in my-theme/languages and the following function in my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
function my_child_theme_setup(){
    load_child_theme_textdomain( '[text-domain]-language', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/languages' );
}
```

I have tried different directories, text-domains and even replaced the .mo files with a completely new one just in case but so far nothing seems to have any sort of effect.

Any help on what I might have done wrong or advice on debugging would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Set path to the folder in functions.php file:

```
load_theme_textdomain('my-theme', get_template_directory().'/languages');
```

Remember that mo files must have correct names. For example: en_US is for English.
If you want to check current language check: [How to determine the current language of a wordpress page when using polylang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118772/how-to-determine-the-current-language-of-a-wordpress-page-when-using-polylang)

Comment: The reason I used get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is because get_template_directory() retrieves the path to the parent theme instead of the child theme. I also made sure my .mo files have the correct names.